# How do I add pre-existing keys SSH to ansible? (crypto)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am very new to ansible.
I have managed to install it and set up the ec2.py file via the git and set up the IAM root user. but my question is I already have a ec2 instance online that uses a .pem file that amazon has created. i use windows and have created the relative .ppk file when i try to ssh into that ec2 instance from another ec2 instance I see that via
cd ~/.ssh/ the files authorized_keys and known_hosts are created
but when i run ssh ubuntu@ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.us-west-2....
I get a permission denied (puplickey) 
I examined the contents of the authorized_keys file and the ppk and pem file and it seems that the public key is stored in the authorized_keys file correctly and the user is correct.
Am I correct in thinking that I need to copy the private key into this file?(although I don't really want to) or is it because I need a passphrase?
and in relation to ansible 
How do I utilise this key to manage the host in the same VPC?

Edit (extra): I found out that the authorized_keys file is the file that contains the public key and fingerprint. when i edited the file i was no longer able to access the EC2 instance and it kept asking for a password and saying that the fingerprint had changed. so I guess that's why its best practice to create a ssh-key on the ansible system and then import into AWS

Comment: "*Am I correct in thinking that I need to copy the private key into this file?*" -- no you are not correct.

Comment: Thanks for confirming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can ssh to the host in question via putty with key.ppk file, then:

- convert `key.ppk` back into `key.pem`
- place `key.pem` somewhere onto the control host (where Ansible is installed)
- define inventory (hosts file) for Ansible:

  `myserver ansible_host=ip-or-dns-of-your-server ansible_user=your-user ansible_ssh_private_key_file=path/to/key.pem`
- run `ansible myserver -m ping` to confirm connectivity

This way Ansible will try to connect to your server aliased `myserver` at `ip-or-dns-of-your-server` with `your-user` account using `path/to/key.pem` private key.